# Apache mod rewrite not working on mac os x lion

Tags: php, macos, apache

I'm trying to set up mod rewrite on os x and it doesn't seem to be working properly.

I've edited my httpd.conf file to include the module, I've changed the AllowOverride setting to "all" in both my httpd.conf and my user.conf file.

Now when I add a htaccess file with the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$ public/        [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
```

I get a 404 not found saying ...

"The requested URL /Users/matt/Sites/framework/public/ was not found on this server."

Even though that folder does exist.

The fact that it's redirecting would suggest that mod rewrite is installed and working, but I'm not sure why I'm getting a 404. Any one else had this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did test your rewrite rule on a Windows machine and it thrown Internal server error. I tweaked it a little bit and came to this solution and it seems to work just fine on my test environment.

Could you give it a try and see if it's ok for you?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^public/ - [L]
RewriteRule .* public/$0 [L]
```

Comment: I tried your suggested code and it still seems to come up with a 404. Do you think maybe my setup is wrong? Maybe something in my conf is pointing to the wrong folder, hence the 404?